# Is it considered good practice to block navigation (popping back) when showing a loader for async tasks?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I feel like blocking the navigation (whether navigation back button or android back button) when having async calls can be frustrating for the user.
However, as a general rule, if navigation was permitted when loading/waiting for async calls, how to avoid async/await code to be executed after popping back? Sometimes alerts get popped up, when you have already gone back to the previous page.

I tried checking if the widget is mounted or the provider is disposed to not execute the async code, but sometimes the aysnc code gets executed before the disposed value turns true.